# What else can I do to my tennis racket to keep the ball in the court?

Tags: equipment, tennis

I like to swing fast and hard....very hard. I get my stress out. But even with a head light tennis racket, on which I've weighted the handle, and top spin, my hits go too far.

I once borrowed a racket, and no matter how hard I hit it the ball stayed in court. Unfortunately I have lost contact with the person who had that racket.

What else can I do to my racket? I was thinking higher tension on the strings. Would that help?

Comment: Generally you need to balance power with control. having very high power and very high control is almost impossible, and that is just the configuration of your racquet. But good technique will trump what is being held in your hand (provided it is still a racquet)

Comment: Higher tension will, if anything, allow higher speeds. Don't do this!

Answer (score 3):

One thing that all tennis players need to know is that the natural instinct of swinging the racquet like a baseball bat is not the best play to make. If you look at most professional players, they don't do full out swings. Instead, they focus more on the top spin by having an angle at the racquet as shown below.[image: As you can see, the racquet would be at an angle and the racquet]

I would say that it is more important to focus on having a topspin and lowering down your swing power. You can read this discussion for more help: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-the-problem-of-hitting-my-tennis-ball-too-far

Answer (score 0):

String tension is extremely important in how much control you have over
the ball you are hitting.  For beginning players a lower string tension
results in the strings helping to power the ball -- but in some ways there
is less control.  With a higher string tension (around 60 lbs) you are
not using the stings to give you power.
   Additionally it might be that a heavier racquet might cause you to
slow down your hitting stroke.